# Hash generator applet doesn't work fine

Tags: hash, md5, javacard

Below, you see an applet that generate hash value of input data based on `MD5`, `RIPEMD160`, `SHA`, `SHA224`, `SHA256`, `SHA384` and `SHA512` :

```
package hashPack;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;
import javacard.security.MessageDigest;

public class HashMachine extends Applet {

    //outputArray
    byte[] hashedValue = new byte[64];

    //output Length
    short OLength = 0x0000;

    //Defining switch case variables for Hash algorithm commands
    final byte MD5 = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte RIPEMD160 = (byte) 0X01;
    final byte SHA = (byte) 0X02;
    final byte SHA224 = (byte) 0X03;
    final byte SHA256 = (byte) 0X04;
    final byte SHA384 = (byte) 0X05;
    final byte SHA512 = (byte) 0X06;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new HashMachine();
    }

    protected HashMachine() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        try {
            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
                case MD5: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_MD5, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 16;

                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case RIPEMD160: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_RIPEMD160, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 20;

                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SHA: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 20;

                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SHA224: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_224, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 32;

                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SHA256: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_256, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 32;
                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SHA384: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_384, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 64;
                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                case SHA512: {
                    MessageDigest HashObj = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_512, false);
                    HashObj.reset();
                    OLength = 64;
                    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] > 0) {
                        doHash(apdu, HashObj, OLength);
                    } else {
                        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
                break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());

        }

    }

    public void doHash(APDU apdu, MessageDigest HashObj, short OLength) {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        HashObj.update(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
        HashObj.doFinal(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC], hashedValue, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(hashedValue, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, OLength);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, OLength);

    }
}
```

The problem is that the values that this applet returns me, are different from the values that online tools return.

For example I want to have hash value of `012345`(in ascii). So I convert it to its hex value (i.e `303132333435`) and I sent it to my applet:

```
OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a4040006C761819104D7 -s 0000000005303132333435
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 C7 61 81 91 04 D7
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00 05 30 31 32 33 34 35
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
40 6B 29 64 5D 4D 8A 75 97 89 84 B5 00 25 67 D2 @k)d]M.u.....%g.
```

As you see the applet returns `40 6B 29 64 5D 4D 8A 75 97 89 84 B5 00 25 67 D2`, while [online tools](http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html)return `d6 a9 a9 33 c8 aa fc 51 e5 5a c0 66 2b 6e 4d 4a`. What's wrong?

Comment: I know that using a static variable for output will ruin the EEPROM soon. I'll change type of this variable. but why the output is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. Your `doHash` method does the hashing as from a twice as long input (it computes the hash from "XX" instead of "X"):

```
HashObj.update(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
HashObj.doFinal(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC], hashedValue, (short) 0);
```

The `update` method is for long inputs only - it does all the computation of the first N data blocks and produces no output. The `doFinal` method does the same for the last block of data and it copies the output to the output buffer.

Use the second line only:

```
HashObj.doFinal(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC], hashedValue, (short) 0);
```